Chnage Connectionstring after publishing maui app
I have created appsetting.json for connectionstring and now after publishing maui app how can i change connectionstring ?
I have tired to access appsetting.json but i couldn't find file after publishment
can anyone give me solution

appsetting.json cannot be changed after you publish the MAUI project. It will be packaged after you publish. You can change it before you publish.

@GuangyuBai-MSFT is there any option that helps to update connectionstring after publushing the app ?

No, you can not get the json file after you publish. The only way to update the connectionstring is that you update it in the visual studio and republish it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You can modify the connection string, but you can't modify the json file that is embeeded in the project.
